# Taking image from gallery and set it to an image view

Tags: java, android, android-bitmap

How to take image from gallery and after selecting an image , set it to Image View

```
Uri uri = data.getData()

InputStream is = null

try
  is = getContentResolver.openInputStream(uri)

catch (FileNotFoundException e)  
    e.printStackTrace();


Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
imageView.setImageURI(uri);
```

on selecting image the app crashed and giving error --

```
unable to decode stream : java.io.fileNotFoundException : 
open failed : ENONENT (No such file or directory)
resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri
```

Comment: Can you edit your post to include code of what you've done so far?

Comment: And include the crash log